# How to see spoilers on touchscreen?

Tags: bug, spoilers

Is there a way to mouseover with an iPod touch?

Comment: Perhaps someone at http://apple.stackexchange.com/ could help with this?

Comment: I'll ask later today, it really is pretty cumbersome navigating these sites on an iPod

Comment: @neilfein http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/6695/how-does-html-mouseover-work-on-apple-multitouch-devices

Comment: I closed because it was a duplicate of one on meta http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75656/cant-see-spoilers-on-touchscreen .  I didn't close as duplicate because the question was on another site.  I didn't close as off-topic because it is a duplicate of one on meta.stackoverflow.com.

Comment: See [my answer here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108090/cant-see-spoilers-on-touchscreen-outside-of-mobile-site/237663#237663).

Answer (score 8):

It doesn't appear so.  [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/reference/safariwebcontent/CreatingContentforSafarioniPhone/CreatingContentforSafarioniPhone.html) says that elements must be clickable in order to have mouseover events work, and as far as I can tell, the spoiler elements are not clickable.

IMO it would be useful for this to be fixed (probably the element can be made clickable, which means that it would still work - but with a tap rather than hovering the mouse).  Perhaps this needs to go to meta.stackexchange.com rather than here, though (since this is also used for the Gaming SE site and perhaps others).

I did a brief search on [meta.gaming.stackexchange.com](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/736/provide-a-markdown-extension-to-hide-text-anti-spoiler) and [meta.stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1037/ability-to-mark-text-as-spoiler-text) and couldn't find any discussion of this issue.  Perhaps the gamers aren't heavy touchscreen users :)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75656/cant-see-spoilers-on-touchscreen